# Live Video Streaming for Android using Phonegap?

Tags: android, html, video, cordova, wowza

I am using WowzaServer Live Streaming type. So I am able to view Video from wowza examples directly using

```
http://[wowza ip address]:1935/live/myStream/Manifest - LIVE Video Streaming Silverlight Player.
http://[wowza ip address]:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8 - LIVE Video Streaming iOS and MAC.
rtmp://[wowza ip address]/live - LIVE Video Streaming Flash RTMP Player
http://[wowza ip address]:1935/live/myStream/manifest.f4m - LIVE Video Streaming Flash HTTP Player
```

I am able to view video from browser using the above links.

I am trying to run the link from a android application and get the video running on android device. I am not able to get the video running.

I tried using the HTML video tag for HLS streaming i.e. I used this:

```
<video id="videohtml" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://[wowza IP address]:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I also tried playing it without using the type.

```
<video id="videohtml" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://[wowza IP address]:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8">
</video>
```

It does not do anything. I am not able to view any video.

I also tried to play `manifest.f4m` stream but no video.

I also tried using the Flowplayer but it asks to install Flash on android application. I also tried using JWPlayer but no video is played.

Can some one please advise me how to play live video stream in android application. I am using Samsung S4 to play the video. I also tried into emulator.

Which is the good video player to be used to play this as there are so many video players and I am a confused as which one to use which will surely play the video on my android device.

Comment: I just answered a similar question.  You should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906181/wowza-rtmp-html5-playback/26429765#26429765, as well as: http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/

Comment: Also, I should mention that I've used the same principles described in the above readings in a PhoneGap project for android with success.

Comment: Hey dude,i am facing same issue.How did u solve it.Please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718171/how-to-use-trendnet-ip-camera-live-streaming-url-in-phonegap-app

Comment: You might want to try crosswalk, it helps you be sure you are running same latest webkit across all android devices and this can solve your issue (apk becomes a bit bigger but it is worth).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 VOD Streaming Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video width="640" height="400" controls="controls" src="http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/vod/[mp4:sample.mp4]/playlist.m3u8">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>`
```

It should work. Please try this.